# Default and Fallback Implementation in Castle windsor

Tags: .net, castle-windsor, castle

Is there a way to register an Interface without an Explicit implementation using Windsor Castle?. I have few interfaces which need implementation in certain cases i.e not need it in other cases for e.g offline mode of my app. In offline, All methods should throw not supported exception; Hence instead creating dummy implementation for all my interfaces, Is there a way in castle to provide a default implementation which does this ?.

Comment: The simplicity of the manual implementation which can be done in few seconds beats the complexity of your desire of automation.

Comment: Reading your explanation I get this feeling something is very odd with your design and perhaps instead of trying to get a tool to do magic a better way to solve it would be to review your approach to not require this odd contraption

Comment: Yes it is odd, But the layer   above my layer (which I do not have control) uses constructor injection of the interfaces which I implement for offline mode(I believe offline was never in picture in the original design) and some of these are not required in offline but without implementation the upper layer can't even created. I am tasked to raise exception if any methods on these not supported interface are invoked.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that what you are trying to do is a right solution. And here is a few ways how to achieve the same in a little bit better way.

**First Approach**

What about using Factory method? :) You can use that factory method to resolve impl of the interface. For instance:

`T Create<T>(ModeEnum mode): where T:YourInterface{
     if(mode==ModeEnum.Offline){
        throw ApplicationOfflineException();
     }
     return instance; // Create somehow instance of a class
}`

In that case, instead of building new type in runtime, you will prevent from resolving that type when app is offline.

With this approach you can go forward, for instance you can mark all classes/interfaces which have some kind of attribute(for instance OnlyOnline). And if the current mode is Offline and a type which you are trying to resolve has attribute [OnlyOnline] than throw ApplicationOfflineException.

**Second approach**

You can use Castle Dynamic proxy. Castle Dynamic Proxy provides AOP functionality. That means that you can execute some kind of logic before running each method of any class that was resolved using IoC container. More info here:
https://github.com/castleproject/Core/blob/master/docs/dynamicproxy.md

Here is an example of CDP interceptor built using Console application that should work for you:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Register(Component.For<PreventOfflineInterceptor>());
        container.Register(
            Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                .BasedOn<IMyClass>()
                .WithServiceAllInterfaces()
                .Configure(c => c.Interceptors<PreventOfflineInterceptor>())
                .LifestyleTransient()
            );
        container.Resolve<IMyClass>().MyMethod();
    }


}
public class PreventOfflineInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public bool IsOffline
    {
        get
        {
            // Get somehow information about mode, is it offline
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        // If the app is not offline lets run the method otherwise throw an exception
        if (IsOffline)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        invocation.Proceed();
    }
}
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyMethod()");
    }
}

public interface IMyClass
{
    void MyMethod();
}
```

Comment: I am currently using typed factory in few places, where I rely on castle provided default implementation of the factory , Is it possible to handle the 1st approach using typed factory ? I assume that, for the first approach, I have to give my own implementation of the factory. right?

Comment: A bit late but yes. You have to define your own factory.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for IHandlerSelector.  This allows you to conditionally select the component you resolve to.  So there's always an explicit component to resolve to because how else would it find the component?

Ayende has article from a long time ago explaining how to implement this https://ayende.com/blog/3633/windsor-ihandlerselector

Here's a more recent article  http://www.longest.io/2015/03/13/select-between-components-castle-windsor.html